Mac Pro 3,1 boot looping and showing “Debugger called: <panic>”
I have an old 3,1 Mac Pro that is boot looping and showing this text (below) when booting up. I can’t seem to get it out of this loop. I was attempting to reinstall the operating system before this started happening. I had erased the main hard drive and then it could not sign in to redownload the operating system. After restarting the Mac it started doing this.
macOS 10.11.6
Error on boot-up screen:
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801d1b41ac): unexpected SIGKILL of init
Debugger called: ‹panic>
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address Bxffffff83bBebb810 : Bxffffff801ccdab52 Oxffffff83b8ebb890 : Oxffffff801d1b41ac
Oxffffff83b8ebb9c0
: 0xffffff801d1994e8
Exffffff83b8ebbd40
: Exffffff801d196b51
Oxffffff83b8ebbdf0
: 0xffffff801d196197
EUxffffff83bBebbe60
: @xffffff801d196531
Oxffffff83bBebbee0
: Oxffffff801d16dF9b
Exffffff83bBebbf00 : 0xffffff801d1b3dd1
Bxffffff83bBebbf40
: Oxffffff801ccd54cd
ExfffffF83b8ebbf 80
: Bxffffff801cdcef3e
Oxffffff83bBebbfa0
: Oxffffff801cdec52f
BSD process name corresponding to current thread: init Boot args: rp-file:///com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.cmg
Mac 0S version:
Not yet set
Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Mon Aug 29 20:21:34 PDT 2016: root:xnu-3248.60.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: E349749B-3303-3DDF-959C-B5885A0E1F6E
Kernel slide:
0x000000001ca00000
Kernel text base: Oxffffff801cc00000
HIB
text base: @xffffff801cb00000
System model name: MacPro3.1 (Mac-F42C88C8)
System uptime in nanoseconds: 2427856660


Your backtrace does not contain symbols. Can you add keepsyms=1 to  boot-args  with sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1" and attach the symbolicated backtrace here?

"sign in to redownload the operating system" Mac Pros don't have Internet Recovery. You need a USB stick… or possibly a CD/DVD [I've had 3,1s since they were new & never managed to get one to boot from USB].
